# Equations In While Loops

Tags: c

This is what I am trying to do: Use the following formula to determine how many feet you will fall per second. Then, print out the elevation of you for each second you are in the air. The last line of output should be the first second that you are back on the ground.

D = ½ * g * t<sup>2</sup>
Assume earth’s gravity is 32 ft/sec<sup>2</sup>.

I'm having a lot of trouble with trying to use equations with while loops in my code. What I am trying to do is have an output like this for example:

```
What is the height?

120

Time Altitude

1........104

2........ 56

3........ 0
```

This is my code right now and I've tried many different things but nothing seems to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define GRAVITY 32
int main() {
    int height, time = 1;
    double distance;

    printf("What is the height?\n");
    scanf("%d", &height);

    printf("Time \tAltitude\n");

    while (height > 0) {
        if (height > 0) {
            distance = .5 * 32 * pow(time, 2);
            printf("%d \t%d", time++, height - distance);
            time++;
        }
        else
            printf("%d \t0", time);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Right now my output is always:

```
What is the height?

(Any number I enter)

Time Altitude

1......0
```

So for some reason it is not entering the first part of the while loop.

Comment: Also the `else` clause will never execute, because the loop terminates if `height <= 0`. And check the result of `scanf`!

Comment: You also need to decrement the height with the distance at some point, or the loop will last forever. `%d` is also not the correct format for printing the result of int-double.

Comment: Do people still really not use the SI (metric) system?  Sad!

Comment: You could usefully start with a line reporting the initial altitude at time t=0.

Comment: Do you see anything wrong with the equation itself, because when time = 2 the outcome is supposed to be 48 but it comes out to 64 for some reason.

Comment: Your code increments `time` twice per loop iteration.

Comment: `time` is the name of a well known system function prototyped in the time.h header file.  In general, variables should not be named the same as the system functions.

Comment: the posted code properly defines 'GRAVITY' so why was that #define name not used in the body of the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several issues...

- You're not passing the correct formatting values to `printf()` in the `while` loop (use `\t%f` instead of `\t%d`).
- You *always* break out of the `while` with a `break`, unconditionally, whatever happens it will break...
- You don't change the value of `height` so that the `while` can exit at some point...
- You're incrementing `time` **twice**!
- For the purposes of fixing all the above, `height` shall have type `double`.
- You're miss-using several operators and functions all over the place, mostly due to the above issues.
- Several design issues (what's the purpose of `GRAVITY`, if you're not using it at all? Why don't you put `'\n'` at the end of `printf()`s?).

Now, given that, the final code may look like... (Note: not checking `scanf()`, but you should!)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define GRAVITY 32

int main() {
    int time = 1;
    double distance = 0;

    printf("What is the height?\n");
    double height;
    scanf("%lf", &height);
    printf("Time\tHeight\n");

    while(height > (distance = 0.5 * GRAVITY * pow(time, 2)))
        printf("%d\t%012lf\n", time++, height - distance);

    printf("Impacted after %lf seconds\n", sqrt(height / (0.5 * GRAVITY)));
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit**: In petition of the OP, the first output line that always printed "Time: 0, height: `input height`" was removed.

Comment: Your objects are falling faster than earth gravity makes them fall.  You shouldn't be subtracting the distance from the height; you should be comparing the distance fallen so far to the height.  It might even be a case for a `do … while` loop.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Heh.. sorry, I'm not too much into physics. Fixed that.

Comment: Yes, that looks correct to me...  I suppose the last line means that if you entered 120 as the height, at t=3, you'll be at height 0 and splatted on the ground.  Maybe a computed value for the time of impact would be interesting, even if not necessarily quite what the OP had in mind.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: How curious. I had too thinked of that while fixing the code. That'ld require `time` to be a `double`, but anyway, editing!

Comment: Time doesn't have to be a double; you calculate `sqrt(height / (0.5 * GRAVITY))` and print that out, don't you?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Well, I had something different in mind, but better of use this. Again, I repeat, I'm not any professional in physics :).

Comment: This was extremely helpful, thank you! But is there a way so that when you enter the height it omits the 0 and height the user entered, so for example if you entered 120 the first thing that would come up under time is 1 and under height is 104, instead of the first thing being 0 under time and 120 under height.

Comment: @GeorgeIVV: Of course! Let me modify the answer with that!

Comment: @GeorgeIVV: that's a weird requirement.  It leaves out an important part of the information.  You have to add 16 to the first reported value to determine the original height.

Answer (score 1):

For `break` statement, your loop is terminated for first run.

Your code is just simple modification. You can try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define GRAVITY 32

int main() {
    int time = 0;
    int height;
    double distance;

    printf("What is the height?\n");
    scanf("%d", &height);
    printf("Time\tHeight\n");

    while(height > 0) {
        printf("%d\t%d\n", time++, height);
        distance = .5 * GRAVITY * pow(time, 2);
        height -= distance;
    }

    printf("%d\t0\n", time);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm It's code is simple and It's better by this format. So you do, I also do

Comment: I didn't understood that... Could you clarify/elaborate a little bit?

Comment: Note what I also said to KernyLand: Your objects are falling faster than earth gravity makes them fall. You shouldn't be subtracting the distance from the height; you should be comparing the distance fallen so far to the height. It might even be a case for a `do … while` loop.   Although, having coded it, I think it is OK to use a `while` loop (and therefore better to do so; `do … while` should be used when necessary, but only when necessary and it is not necessary here).

Answer (score -1):

1. You did not initialize the `height` variable, assuming it will be zero by default therefore the while is never executed.
2. If you did enter `height`, the program would never end because you are not resetting the value. It will only break when the `height` is 0 or less value.
3. You don't need a while loop to do the calculation.
4. If you want to run the program recursively then  put the `printf` and `scanf` in a `while` loop, and have instructions to enter '-1'  to exit.

Comment: (1) `height` was initialized by `scanf()`.  Granted, the code didn't check that it was successful, but it was initialized.  (2) Correct.  However, it is probably best to use `height > distance` in the condition, having set time and distance to zero before the loop.  (3) I think you do need the loop; for big enough initial heights, it will take multiple seconds to fall the whole distance.  (4) Yes, that's a valid improvement.  Detecting EOF would also be a good idea (that would go along with checking the return value from `scanf()`).